# Get today's date in yyyy-mm-dd format in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a way where I can get today's date in Pig Script in yyyy-mm-dd format. I am unable to get hold of any API for that.

Thanks

Comment: You should accept an answer if it solved your question. If it did not, then you should comment on it asking for more clarifications.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a `TODAYS_DATE` variable like this:

```
%default TODAYS_DATE `date +%Y-%m-%d`;
```

and refer to it every time you need by inserting `$TODAYS_DATE` in the string:

```
'/data/mydata/$TODAYS_DATE'
```

Make sure to make no typing mistakes. You may also use `%declare`, but you will lose the flexibility to override the value from the command line or parameter file.

Comment: When I do this, it gives me an error ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered " <PATH> "%default "" at line 1, column 1.

Comment: I think your first comment is OK %default TODAYS_DATE `date  +%Y/%m/%d`. I see that in other piece of code in my software as well. But when I try to run in on grunt shell it gives an error.

Comment: My bad, made a parse error with the `;`. It should work now :)

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped solving your problem.

Comment: It's still not working. Pig 0.12 gives the error: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered " <PATH> "%default "" at line 1, column 1

Comment: I had to pass the variable as an input to pig instead of typing it in the script. That way it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `ToString(CurrentTime(),'yyyy-MM-dd') as date:chararray` in your **pig** script.